# How to SQL query a table using a "for any two rows" statement

Tags: sql, select

Can I make a SQL query which does the following: For any two distinct rows in table T, r1 and r2, let r1.ID = X and r2. ID = Y. select the pair of IDs (X,Y) if X + Y = 5.

I thought of using the following query from the [W3 School example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp)

```
SELECT CustomerID AS X, CustomerID AS Y FROM Customers WHERE X+Y=5;
```

But that doesn't seem to satisfy the "For any two distinct rows in table T" condition.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a `join`:

```
select c1.id, c2.id
from Customers c1 join
     Customers c2
     on c1.id + c2.id = 5 and c1.id < c2.id;
```

Note that this satisfies the "distinct" rule because of the `<`.  A specific row cannot be chosen for both `c1` and `c2`.

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution!

Answer (score 2):

Use `JOIN` with appropriate condition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE WHEN c1.ID > c2.ID THEN c2.ID ELSE c1.ID END AS CustomerID1, 
CASE WHEN c1.ID > c2.ID THEN c1.ID ELSE c2.ID END AS CustomerID2 
FROM Customers c1
JOIN Customers c2 ON c1.ID <> c2.ID AND c1.SomeValue + c2.SomeValue = 5
```

You should use `DISTINCT` clause because other way you will get duplicates. 
Suppose you table has rows:

```
ID   Value
1    2
2    3
```

Without case expressions you will get:

```
CustomerID1 CustomerID2
1           2
2           1
```

With case expressions you get:

```
CustomerID1 CustomerID2
1           2
1           2
```

That's why you need to apply `DISTINCT` clause.